# Unable to install argo workflow cron as a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argoproj

I wanted to install an argo workflow template and workflow cron job as a helm chart.
helm install command says the chart is installed. But I see only workflow template got deployed and cron job isnt.

**Folder structure:**

```
Argo_helm
 |- templates
     |-azure-migration-cron-etl.yaml
     |-azure-migration-etl-template.yaml
 |-Chart.yaml
 |-values.yaml
```

When executed helm install command, I see as follows

```
 helm upgrade --install argo-helm-charts --values values.yaml . 

WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /Users/e192270/.kube/config
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /Users/e192270/.kube/config
Release "argo-helm-charts" does not exist. Installing it now.
NAME: argo-helm-charts
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Feb  8 11:28:01 2021
NAMESPACE: argo
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
```

When I list template I can see it

```
$ argo template list   
                                                                                                               
NAME
test-azure-migration
```

But **unable** to see cron installed as a part of chart

```
argo cron list -n argo 
NAME              AGE   LAST RUN   NEXT RUN   SCHEDULE      SUSPENDED
```

==========================================================================

**cron code (azure-migration-cron-etl.yaml)**

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.workflow_name }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.workflow_namespace }}
  labels:
    workflows.argoproj.io/controller-instanceid: fp
spec:
  schedule: "0 1 * * *"
  timezone: "America/Chicago"
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: sparkdatabricks-app
    metrics:
      prometheus:
        - name: dim_bud_etl_duration
          labels:
            - key: team
              value: foundational-projects-data-eng
          help: "Duration of dim_bud etl"
          gauge:
            value: "{{`{{workflow.duration}}`}}"
    serviceAccountName: argo-s3-service-account
    volumes:
      - name: bearer-token
        secret:
          secretName: databricks-bearer-token-ophie
    templates:
      - name: sparkdatabricks-app
        steps:
          - - name: create-databricks-cluster
              templateRef:
                name:  azure-migration-template
                template: databricks-api
              arguments:
                parameters:
                  - name: databricks-api-command
........
.......
```

**template code (azure-migration-etl-template.yaml)**

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.workflow_template_name}}
  namespace: argo
spec:
  entrypoint: databricks-api
  serviceAccountName: fp-argo-workflow
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: databricks-api-command
        value: ""
  templates:
    - name: databricks-api
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: databricks-api-command
      container:
        image: basic-ubuntu:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: [sh,-c]
        args: [{{`"{{inputs.parameters.databricks-api-command}}"`}}]
        env:
          - name: BEARER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: databricks-bearer-token-ophie
                key: bearer
          - name: ACCOUNT
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: databricks-bearer-token-ophie
                key: account
        volumeMounts:
          - name: bearer-token
            mountPath: "/secret/mountpath"
      outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: id       # can be any id depends on what databricks api call it is
            valueFrom:
              path: /tmp/info.txt
```

**values.yaml**

```
workflow_name: v-dim-bud-test
workflow_namespace: argo
workflow_template_name: test-azure-migration
```

Comment: Can you also add the contents of your values.yaml?

Comment: updated values.yaml in description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argo allows you to [scale vertically by adding multiple workflow controllers](https://argoproj.github.io/argo/scaling/#instance-id). Each controller gets an "instance ID."

Your CronWorkflow specifies the `fp` workflow controller instance.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.workflow_name }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.workflow_namespace }}
  labels:
    workflows.argoproj.io/controller-instanceid: fp
```

To list CronWorkflows managed by the `fp` workflow controller instance, us the `--instanceid` parameter:

```
$ argo cron list -n argo --instanceid fp
NAME             AGE   LAST RUN   NEXT RUN   SCHEDULE    SUSPENDED
v-dim-bud-test   3m    N/A        12h        0 1 * * *   false
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Though I have a question. With instance_id, I was able to view cron list if implemented using cron command. why is it so?

$argo cron create azure-migration-cron-etl.yaml -n argo

Name:                azure-migration-template
Namespace:           argo
Created:             Mon Feb 08 13:15:52 -0600 (now)

$ argo cron list -n argo
NAME                       AGE   LAST RUN   NEXT RUN   SCHEDULE      SUSPENDED
azure-migration-cron-etl   9s    N/A        11h        0 1 * * *     false

Comment: @saranyaelumalai it's a little difficult to read, but I _think_ you've created a CronWorkflow using the `argo` CLI without an `instanceid` specified. (In the Helm chart, `instanceid` is specified as a label.) So that CronWorkflow is going to be managed by the default workflow controller and therefore is going to show up in `argo list` without `instanceid` specified. Does that make sense?